# Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

Tags: c++

So I get error when using this piece of code in third line. What can cause this error?

```
struct Metadata
{
struct Metadata(char* key, char* value)
{
    strcpy(this->key, key);
    strcpy(this->value, value);
    next = NULL;
}
char key[SIZE_KEY];
char value[SIZE_VALUE];
struct Metadata* next;
};
```

Comment: Your nested struct should also end with a semicolon.

Comment: What do you think the third line is supposed to mean?

Comment: This is C++, not C. The only appearance of `struct` in this piece of code should be on line 1. Also: use `std::string` instead of character arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To create a constructor, you don't have to type struct before it, simply removing struct on line 3 will fix it.